# Labview : re-displaying x label of waveform graph

Tags: graph, labview

I've lost x label of my waveform graph.

My original waveform graph looks like this.

[image]

But, for some reasons, x label of the graph was disappeared, like this.

[image]

I checked the property of the graph. The x scale property looks like this.

[image]

As you can see, x label(time (sec)) is there in x scale  property, and then the 'Show scale label check box' is checked, but not displayed on GUI.

Where is the label? How to display it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Apparrently one can make the x-label visible again by right-clicking on the indicator --> Advanced --> Reset Scale Layout

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened here, unless you share this control (may be copy it on a blank VI and share across).
However You can try following to check if you are able to see the label for x-axis:
a. right click the graph indicator and select ADVANCE >> CUSTOMIZE.
b. Now press 'ctrl+M' to switch to 'Customize Mode'.
c. Now check if you can find the x-axis label.

The easiest way to get this resolved, is by replacing the existing graph by right clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your graph on the front panel, highlight '*X Scale*' and make sure '*Visible Scale Label*' is selected.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: That's strange, is it possible to have a copy of a vi with this graph?